# Native token fee

Tags: token, fee, offchain, native

I want to implement native token in a digital wallet.
But I don't want users to have to pay a fee every time they transact with my token.
On the other hand, I want the transactions to be recorded at some point in the blockchain.
Is there a mechanism to resolve this scenario? off-chain? Do you know any project that does this or something similar?

Comment: This seems to be a good use case for Hydra, from what I know so far about it. But I cannot give you more details, you will have to search for the documentation yourself. I know about this repository: https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc - maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

UTxOs with native tokens are larger than those without, which results in slightly larger transaction inputs and outputs. Larger transactions have higher fees, there's no getting round that onchain. You can use a short or blank token name to minimises cost to transact with your token.